# System of 2 first-order DE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Got some trouble with the following, I don't exactly have an idea how to approach this, the textbook is lacking me the information I need:

$$
\frac{du}{dt}=Au(t)
$$

With $A\in R^{2\times2}$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0, \\
3 & -4 
\end{pmatrix}$

The question is to determine the solution of this system according to an initial condition $u(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
-6 & 7
\end{pmatrix}^T$

Where the solution must be given in the form $u(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
u_1(t) & u_2(t)
\end{pmatrix}^T$

I've tried calculating $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$, however, one will return $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^T$ and thus I'm unable to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: plug the general solution of your first equation ($u_1'=5u_1$) into your 2nd equation ($u'_2=\dots$). Once you have the general solution of the system, handle the initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this a $2 \times 2$ system, the simplest way is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.  $A$ is triangular, so the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements $\lambda_1 = 5 , \lambda_2 = -4$

The corresponding eigenvectors are

$ \zeta_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \zeta_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now express the initial condition in terms of $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$, by inspection,

$ u(0) = [-6, 7]^T = -2 \zeta_1 + 9 \zeta_2 $

Therefore, the solution is

$ u(t) = -2 e^{5 t} \zeta_1 + 9 e^{-4t} \zeta_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -6 e^{5 t} \\ -2 e^{5t} + 9 e^{-4t} \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally assumed the vector $\xi_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$, where it should have been $\xi_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$. Thank you for clearing that up. Completely missed a tiny error.